# AWK make a simple subtract and find the minimum value of that

Tags: linux, awk

I have this matrix:

```
{{1,4},{6,8}}
```

and I want to substract the second value from the first value like: 4-1 and 8-6
and then, comparer both and show what was the minimun value from both, in this case: 8-6=2

All of this using AWK in terminal

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you please post sample Input and expected output too.

Comment: What form is the matrix in? Is it in a file? Or in a bash variable? Does it actually have all braces and commas and rubbish in it?

Comment: It is not clear why you have to use Awk as Awk is more specialized and very efficient at processing data line by line such as, but not restricted to, a csv file. Maybe your can give more context to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You seem a little confused about whether you want to subtract the first from the second or the second from the first. Also, about whether your data is in a file or a variable. However, this should get you started...

If we replace any mad braces or commas with spaces:

```
echo "{{1,4},{6,8}}" | awk '{gsub(/[{},]/," "); print}'
1 4   6 8
```

Now we can access the fields as `$1` through `$4` and do what you want:

```
echo "{{1,4},{6,8}}" | awk '{gsub(/[{},]/," "); x=$2-$1; y=$4-$3; if(x<y)print x; else print y}'
2
```

---

As a, maybe more elegant, alternative suggested by @3161993 in the comments, you could set the field separator to be one or more open or close braces or commas, like this:

```
awk -F '[,{}]+' '{x=$3-$2; y=$5-$4; if(x<y) print x; else print y}' <<< "{{1,4},{6,8}}"
2
```

---

And, as @EdMorton kindly pointed out, it can be made a bit more succinct with a ternary operator like this:

```
awk -F '[,{}]+' '{x=$3-$2; y=$5-$4; print (x<y ? x : y)}' <<< "{{1,4},{6,8}}"
```

Comment: Mmmm... you need an asterisk afterwards to pick up $3, and then you don't get $4.

Comment: Yeah, with `-F'[{},]+'`  you can access `$2,$3,$4,$5`, you may add if you wish ++

Comment: @3161993 I have added it in and credited you - thanks for sharing your insights.

Comment: You are welcome, there's no need of credit and all, we all here to share what we know... good day....

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you - I tried to do exactly that when I first started but couldn't quite nail the syntax. I think I had `x<y ? print x; : print y` which doesn't work.

Comment: You're welcome, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: for more info on ternary expressions if you care but they're just `(condition ? value if true : value if false)` and the `value if` parts can call a function/builtin that returns that value but `print` does not return a value.